# pass argument into method from Map AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How to pass an argument into method when is in map?

I'm trying to create excel file with dynamic values from table. In map I have some references to records in table like BOM.BOMid and I want to pass this like an argument to this function not like str:

```
Map  map = new Map(Types::Integer, Types::Container);
MapEnumerator en = new MapEnumerator(map); 

map.insert(1, bom.ItemId);

xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,column).value(<value from map>);column++;
```

Comment: Which table map are you using? And could you show some more of your code and the current and expected output?

Comment: I'm using Map as collection - not from Data Dictionary

Answer (score 4):

If you used `map.insert(1, bom.ItemId);` to add an element to the map, you can retrieve the value as follows:

```
Map map = new Map(Types::Integer, Types::String);
ItemId value;
...
if (map.exists(1))
{
    value = map.lookup(1);
}
```

You can also make use of `MapEnumerator` as follows:

```
//int key;
...
MapEnumerator en = map.getEnumerator();
while (enum.moveNext())
{
    //key = enum.currentKey();
    value = enum.currentValue();
    ...
}
```